# Help me put on the shirt

Tags: grammar

He took the shirt to me and said,

"**Help me put on the shirt.**"

Does it grammatically correct and sound natural to a native speaker?

Comment: "Help me put on the shirt." does but "He took the shirt to me and said," does not

Comment: Do you have a more specific question (for example about *help* versus *help to*)?

Comment: @snailplane I think It might to complicate to a kid. It doesn't sound like a kid will say. What are the alternative way to say. Make it simple.

Comment: I'd say, **"Help me put the shirt on"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Help me put on the shirt" is grammatically correct, but does not sound natural. "He took the shirt to me and said" is neither. I suggest:

> He brought me the shirt and said, "Help me put this on"

Answer (score 1):

**"Help me put on the shirt"** sounds absolutely correct and natural, however, I as a non-native speaker would place the preposition at the end **"Help me put the shirt on"**